# How do I check to see if an array of arrays has a value within the inner arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Say I have an array of arrays that looks like this:

```
[[1830, 1], [1859, 1]]
```

What I want to do is quickly scan the internal arrays to see if any of them contain the number `1830`. If it does, I want it to return the entire array that includes the number `1830`, aka `[1830, 1]` from the above example.

I know for a normal array of values, I would just do `array.include? 1830`, but that doesn't work here, as can be seen here:

```
@add_lines_num_start
#=> [[1830, 1], [1859, 1]]
@add_lines_num_start.include? 1830
#=> false
@add_lines_num_start.first.include? 1830
#=> true
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Suppose the array was `[[1830,1], [2, 1830], [3, 1492]]` and the number of interest was `1830`. Is `[[1830,1], [2, 1830]]` to be returned?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a = [[1830, 1], [1859, 1]]
a.find { |ar| ar.grep(1830) }
#=> [1830, 1]
```

References:

- [Enumerable#`find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find)
- [Enumerable#`grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep)

## edit 1

As @Ilya mentioned in comment, instead of traversing the whole array with `grep` you could use the method to return the boolean once element that matches the condition is found:

```
a.find { |ar| ar.include?(1830) }
```

References:

- [Enumerable#`include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-include-3F)

## edit 2 (shamelessly stolen from @Cary's comment under OP)

In case you'll have more than one matching array in your array, you can use [Enumerable#`find_all`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_all):

```
a = [[1830, 1], [1859, 1], [1893, 1830]]
a.find_all { |ar| ar.include?(1830) }
#=> [[1830, 1], [1893, 1830]]
```

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @marcamillion no probs :)

Comment: `include?` seems to be more readable, moreover: it's more efficient, you don't scan a whole array in this case.

Comment: @AlexGolubenko yea, `select` is an alias of `find_all` :)